# Statistical test for time series where outcome occurs - python

Tags: python, pandas, regression

I am enquiring about assistance regarding regression testing. I have a continuous time series that fluctuates between positive and negative integers. I also have *events* occurring throughout this time series at seemingly random time points. Essentially, when an event occurs I grab the respective integer. I then want to test whether this integer influences the event at all. As in, are there more positive/negative integers.

I originally thought logistic regression with the positive/negative number but that would require at least two distinct groups. Whereas, I only have info on events that have occurred. I can't really include that amount of events that don't occur as it's somewhat continuous and random. The amount of times an event doesn't occur is impossible to measure.

So my distinct group is all true in a sense as I don't have any results from something that didn't occur. What I am trying to classify is:

**When an outcome occurs, does the positive or negative integer influence this outcome**.

Comment: This is not a programming question, so not really the right place to ask.  I'd probably classify it as a modeling question, but without nearly enough info to answer even if it this were the correct forum.  People take multiple college classes to answer questions like this.  You need to do a lot of learning, or hire someone!

Comment: Fair point with programming. I don't expect a detailed answer. Just some suggestions with high level approaches.

Comment: Still, you might have a better answer in https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are interested in determining the underlying forces that are producing a given stream of data. Such mathematical models are called Markov Models. A classic example is the study of text.

For example, if I run a Hidden Markov Model algorithm on a paragraph of English text, then I will find that there are two driving categories that are determining the probabilities of what letters show up in the paragraph. Those categories can be roughly broken into two groups, "aeiouy " and "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz". Neither the mathematics nor the HMM "knew" what to call those categories, but they are what is statistically converged to upon analysis of a paragraph of text. We might call those categories "vowels" and "consonants". So, yes, vowels and consonants are not just 1st grade categories to learn, they follow from how text is written statistically. Interestingly, a "space" behaves more like a vowel than a consonant. I didn't give the probabilities for the example above, but it is interesting to note that "y" ends up with a probability of roughly 0.6 vowel and 0.4 consonant; meaning that "y" is the most consonant behaving vowel statistically.

A great paper is https://www.cs.sjsu.edu/~stamp/RUA/HMM.pdf which goes over the basic ideas of this kind of time-series analysis and even provides some sudo-code for reference.

I don't know much about the data that you are dealing with and I don't know if the concepts of "positive" and "negative" are playing a determining factor in the data that you see, but if you ran an HMM on your data and found the two groups to be the collection of positive numbers and collection of negative numbers, then your answer would be confirmed, yes, the most influential two-categories that are driving your data are the concepts of positive and negative. If they don't split evenly, then your answer is that those concepts are not an influential factor in driving the data. Regardless, in the end, the algorithm would end with several probability matricies that would show you how much each integer in your data is being influenced by each category, hence you would have much greater insight in the behavior of your time-series data.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was after. I'm not sure what's going on with the bounty. I think it timed out?

Comment: No worries. :-)

Comment: It was amazing to learn this concept and you explained it really well.

Answer (score 0):

Although, the question is quite difficult to understand after first paragraph. Let me help from what I could understand from this question.

Assuming you want to understand if there is relationship between the events happening and the integers in the data.

1st approach: Plot the data on a 2d scale and check visually if there is a relationship between data.
2nd approach: make the data from the events continuous and remove the events from other data and using rolling window smooth out the data and then compare both trends.

Above given approach only works well if I am understanding your problem correctly. 
There is also one more thing known as Survivorship bias. You might be missing data, please also check that part also.

Comment: I've done the first approach. I alluded to survivorship bias not being relevant. I'm not missing data.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I am misunderstanding your problem but I don't believe that you can preform any kind of meaningful regression without more information.

Regression is usually used to find a relationship between two or more variables, however It appears that you only have one variable (if they are positive or negative) and one constant (outcome is always true in data). Maybe you could do some statistics on the distribution of the numbers (mean, median, standard deviation) but I am unsure how you might do regression.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis

You might want to consider that there might be some strong survivorship bias if you are missing a large chunk of your data.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivorship_bias

Hope this is at least a bit helpful to get you steered in the right direction